# Get original parameter input - Dialogflow Fulfillment

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to get the original input of a parameter in my fulfillment code.

I tried:

```
var time = agent.parameters.time.original
```

but the result was undefined.

I have tried:

```
var query = agent.query
```

but could not accurately parse the parameter I need the original input of.

Comment: Are you using Actions on Google Node.js client library?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov Not using for this function, but it is a dependency.

Comment: Could you paste in the value of `agent.parameters` at the point that this code is running?

`console.log(agent.parameters)`

Comment: @techpeace Sure, it is `{ time: '2018-08-01T15:00:00+01:00', openclose: 'open', date: '2018-08-01T09:52:34+01:00' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [an answer on the old API.ai discourse forums](https://discuss.api.ai/t/problem-getting-parameter-original-from-webhook/10254/2), it looks like original parameters may only be available in a webhook fulfillment request if you set a context on the intent. At that point, the original parameter should be available in the `contexts` key in the request.

Comment: This is correct, most people should be able easily obtain this using `agent.request_.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters['paramname.original']; ` provided they have set any context with an active lifespan.

Comment: I should also note that Google made the decision to discontinue the old API.ai Discourse forums, so the above link no longer works. I've left the link in place in case they ever reverse that decision.

Answer (score 3):

The actual name of the original value used for the parameter is "time.original". In order to get this, you need to use something like

```
var time = agent.parameters['time.original'];
```

What you were trying was to get an attribute of `agent.parameters.time` named `original` instead of an attribute of `agent.parameters` named `time.original`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but the result is `undefined` when I do that. It could be because the parameter value is not the original value. I need both the proper ISO date string and the original input.

Answer (score 3):

The solution i found as dated 3rd-Apr-2019 is following

Add custom parameter with `actual entity name` heaving value `$yourparametername.orignal`

[image: Add custom parameter with Actual entity name heaving value $yourparametername.orignal]

And get its value like that 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

var time = agent.contexts[0].parameters['time.original']